# How to echo out php variable which is a div with multiple child div on specific id using JS or any other method?

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to echo out the divs on js such as

> `$("#id").append("<?php echo $var_with_multi_div;?>")`

But since with div are printed on a new line the console gives error -

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

So, how can I print the PHP variable on a specific element of the HTML page using JS? Is there any method to append as a child on an element without JS?

Comment: Try wrapping the output in single quotes: `append('<?= $your_divs ?>')` since the contents already contains double quotes (which is what currently creates the syntax error). Also, please add the contents and output to the question _as text_ instead of an image. Please read Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I tried using a single quote but still gives an error - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: Here's the similar problem - https://jsfiddle.net/shahmanish/mtfep5zs/1/